# Using raw_input after using print command

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, printing

this is my first post forgive me if I am doing something wrong or possibly my grammar, I have just started my journey with python currently using v2.

problem so far is I want the user to be able to press any key to continue
after I've used the "print" command, so far I have this

"print 'We have been awaiting your arrival!' + raw_input"

This is for a text adventure game as my first project and want that classic 
press any key after text is given rather than text commenting

"Press any key to continue"

I'm sure this might be a simple task, please be nice first post and glad
to join the community.

Comment: Post your actual code, and what's going wrong. What you've posted is either horribly mangled (trying to add string and function) or pseudo code you've never actually run. For the record, `raw_input` takes an argument that it prints as the prompt, so `print` isn't even needed here.

Comment: I think your right i was trying to add a string and function, I had seen other commands been combined together so had thought this may have been possible but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether you have any previous experience with other languages, but raw_input is not a variable as you have attempted to use it, but rather a method call. Using https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input as a reference, we can see that raw_input() is a function which takes the next users input, and stores it in a string. If we do not want to store it in a string, as in your case, we can simply use it to wait until the user presses enter. To directly answer your question, you are probably interested in using something along the lines of:

```
print("Press any key to continue")
raw_input();
```